# notation question about positive differential (p,p) form

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$, we say $ u \in \Lambda^{p,p}V^*$ is positive if for all $\alpha_j \in V^*$, $1 \leq j \leq q = n-p$, we have $u \wedge i\alpha_1 \wedge \bar{\alpha_1} \wedge ... \wedge i\alpha_q \wedge \bar{\alpha_q}$ is a positive $(n,n)$ form. (Demailly Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry, page 130)

I have seen the notation to denote $u$ to be a positive $(p,p)$ form to be $u > 0$. I have also seen notation $u > v$ for $u,v$ $(p,p)$ form. Does the second notation the same as $u-v > 0$,i.e, a positive form?

Comment: Yes. This should be universal in mathematics. :)

Comment: thanks for clarifying